# Big Integer and Double Conversion

Tags: java, types, double, biginteger

I am trying the below computation.

```
 double k = 2015 * Math.pow(10, 10) + 12 * Math.pow(10, 8) + 25 * Math.pow(10, 6)
                + 12 * Math.pow(10, 4) + 30 * Math.pow(10, 2) + 59 + 1;
```

Why Java is not allowing me to save this number as Big Integer? It always prompts me to use data type double.

I tried converting the k into Big Integer as follows

```
    BigInteger t = BigDecimal.valueOf(k).toBigInteger();
```

My **k** value was **2.015122512306E13**   After conversion, my Big Integer **t** has the value  **20151225123060** .

Comment: Could you please elaborate? The conversion is fine: `2.015122512306E13` is `2.015122512306 * 10^13` so `20151225123060`

Comment: Why Java is not allowing me to save the number as Big Integer? It always prompts me to use data type double . Regarding the variable k.

Comment: ...because it's a double? It's not a BigInteger.

Comment: Do you want to save that expression (2015 * Math.pow()....) directly into a BigInteger? If so, you can't since `Math.pow()` retruns a **double** (primitive). You have to create an istance of a BigDecimal, then you can get the BigInteger, as you did. You could also create a BigInteger.valueOf(2015), then execute the same operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Java is designed in such way. Method `Math.pow()` return `double`. That's why the result of all multiplications and additions in your expression is also `double`. So the result of the expression is `double`. That's why you can directly assign it only to a variable of type `double`.

You can also cast it and assign to variables of other *primitive* types like `float` or `long`. But for BigInteger there is no primitive type and you cannot cast it. Instead, you have to explicitly create a variable of type BigInteger.

In the current form of expression you can loose some of the last digits if you use bigger numbers, namely when the number consists of more than 16 decimal digits. That's why I'd suggest you to use BigInteger in all parts of such expressions like following:

```
BigInteger k = 
        BigInteger.valueOf(2015).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(10))
        .add(BigInteger.valueOf(12).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(8)))
        .add(BigInteger.valueOf(25).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(6)))
        .add(BigInteger.valueOf(12).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(4)))
        .add(BigInteger.valueOf(30).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(2)))
        .add(BigInteger.valueOf(59))
        .add(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
```

Such expression might look complex. In such case check if you really need BigInteger. If you do need, you have to accept this price for *arbitrary* precision integers. Alternatively, consider other platforms instead of Java, but many of them (e.g. R, Python) have similar syntax for big integer numbers.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the statement you can take advantage of shorter `constant` values as well as defining your own, in this case `ten`.  This can reduce some of the cumbersomeness of working with `BigInteger` as well as reduce the likelyhood of errors.  Since `BigInteger` is an immutable class, `ten` will not change its value.

```
        BigInteger ten = BigInteger.TEN; // Constant defined in BigInteger
        BigInteger k = 
                BigInteger.valueOf(2015).multiply(ten.pow(10))
                .add(BigInteger.valueOf(12).multiply(ten.pow(8)))
                .add(BigInteger.valueOf(25).multiply(ten.pow(6)))
                .add(BigInteger.valueOf(12).multiply(ten.pow(4)))
                .add(BigInteger.valueOf(30).multiply(ten.pow(2)))
                .add(BigInteger.valueOf(59))
                .add(BigInteger.ONE); // Constant defined in BigInteger
        System.out.println(k);
```